# How to define Histogram categories/intervals

Tags: highcharts

Based on the histogram sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/samples/highcharts/demo/histogram/

```
var data = [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Histogram'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Data' },
        alignTicks: false
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Histogram' },
        alignTicks: false,
        opposite: true
    }],

    yAxis: [{
        title: { text: 'Data' }
    }, {
        title: { text: 'Histogram' },
        opposite: true
    }],

    series: [{
        name: 'Histogram',
        type: 'histogram',
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        baseSeries: 's1',
        zIndex: -1
    }, {
        name: 'Data',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: data,
        id: 's1',
        marker: {
            radius: 1.5
        }
    }]
});
```

Is it possible to define the categories to be used in the x axis? Either define the number of categories (like 5 categories) or define the values used in each category (like 2-2.5, 2.6-3.0, 3.1-3.5, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zone` and the `zoneAxis` for this [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zoneAxis)

```
{
    name: 'Histogram',
    type: 'histogram',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: 's1',
    zIndex: -1,
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
        value: 2.5,
        color: '#f00'
    }, {
        value: 3,
        color: '#f50'
    }, {
            value: 3.5,
        color: '#fa5'
    }, {
        value: 4,
        color: '#f0f'
    }, {
            value: 4.5,
        color: '#0f5'
    }],
    binsNumber: 5,
    binWidth:0.5
}
```

**Edit**
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ursdmq7e/2)

Comment: That will only color the existing automatic categories, it does not define new ones.

Comment: Highcarts creates 13 categories for that example. I need the histogram to have only 5 or 7 for example.

Comment: @JoãoGomes Look the update I made, so now you have 5 columns with 5 colors.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.